# CSS-How to display panel on hover of i tag

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to open popup panel when the user hovers over a shopping cart icon, like [this example from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_clothing_store&stacked=h).

This is a similar idea to SO's inbox:

[image: Screenshot]

I tried [this code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1B1V3AP9RB1), but it looks like I am missing something.

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart w3-margin-right dropdown" onmouseover="javascript:void(0)"></i>
<div class="dropdown-content"><p>This is a test</p></div>
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

Comment: The code given in your example is not reflective of the code you showed while pairing.  Please update to be your current code so others can help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a + sign since it is a sibling element.

Tried to add css:

```
.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jennifergoncalves/zy0m1w32/2/

(used "Hello" since I don't have font awesome loaded in)

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Spaces are used for parent/child relationships.

UPDATE:
After speaking in chat, the HTML posed in the question was not the same as the actual code.

Actual HTML:

```
<p class="w3-right">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart w3-margin-right dropdown" onmouseover="javascript:void(0)"></i>
</p>
<div class="dropdown-content">
    <p> This is a test</p>
</div>
```

The sibling selector wasn't working because "dropdown" and "dropdown-content" were not actually siblings.  Adding the "dropdown" class to the "p" tag seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Does the fiddle work as desired?  If yes, I can help you get it into your code.

Comment: Fiddle is working. But not at the template at my link.

Comment: Can you send me your link?  I can debug there.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1B2V5LK0V4W Thanks for spending time

Comment: want to make change here: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_clothing_store&stacked=h

Comment: Can you start a chat?  We can debug there.  I see a few things going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use '+' or '~' like below:

```
.dropdown:hover + .dropdown-content {
    //your css code
}
.dropdown:hover ~ .dropdown-content {
    //your css code
}
```